# Java code similar to "curl / grep"

Tags: java, curl, grep

In the terminal, if I use the command,

```
curl -u username:passw -v https://example.com/rest/prototype/1/content/123456 | grep VALUE-I-WANT
```

it returns the value that I want.
How do I replicate this in Java?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use [`Runtime.getRuntime.exec()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29).

For example, to get a registry value for the default browser on Windows:

```
String command = "curl -u username:passw -v https://example.com/rest/prototype/1/content/123456 | grep VALUE-I-WANT";
try
{
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
} catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then use a `Scanner` to get the output of the command, if necessary.

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
```

**Note**: the `\` is an escape character in a `String`, and must be escaped to work properly . Also this is just a reference for help, not the pre-cooked actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Or besides above answer if you want use Http client to hit the url and then parse the data to get result http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/

The good thing will be if you want to have post hits / requests, you can easily do that

for post you can have a method like

```
public Map<String, String> postData(String url, Map<String, String> headerMap, Map<String, String> formMap) throws IOException {

        CustomRedirectStratergy customRedirectStratergy = new CustomRedirectStratergy();
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        StringBuilder builder = null;

//        LOGGER.info("hiturl {} ",url);

        if (headerMap != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headerMap.entrySet()) {
//                LOGGER.info("headers ---- {}, {}",entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                httpPost.setHeader(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }

        if (formMap != null) {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : formMap.entrySet()) {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry
                        .getValue()));
            }
            UrlEncodedFormEntity form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
            httpPost.setEntity(form);
        }

        httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().
                setRedirectStrategy(customRedirectStratergy).
                setDefaultRequestConfig(globalConfig).
                setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).
                build();

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        Charset charset = ContentType.getOrDefault(httpEntity).getCharset();
        if (charset == null) {
            charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
        }

        Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
        resultMap.put(CLIENT_RESPOSNE, EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), charset));
        resultMap.put(LAST_REDIRECT, customRedirectStratergy.getRedirectionLocation());

        return resultMap;
    }
```

Its obvious you need to override customRedirectStratergy to get if there is any redirect.

Then use any parser (maybe JSOUP parser) to do what you like

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: That comment makes currently no sense to me. Can you rewrite it? Or explain what you mean..